# How to show progress towards achieving different goals, if goals are in one table and activities in another

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder, multiple-tables

I am working with Laravel 5.7. In my application users complete a form, linked to a goals table, to define their goals (number of activities to complete, by type of activity, between a start date and end date).  Users can have as many goals as they like.

Another form is used to record details of each completed activity (linked to activities table), by date and type of activity. Both tables contain linked unique user_ids.

For each unique goal (goal id), I need to find all the completed activities that match that goal and, importantly, total the number of activities completed against each goal.

The aim is to have a table that details each goal and, in the same table, shows the progress against each unique goal.

Please help as I have been stuck on this for a long time and I'm only a beginner!

I've inner joined the goals and activities tables by unique user_id and set where clauses to match completed activities with the goal criteria.

I only manage to get a total amount of completed activities ($progress_against_goal) for ALL goals. I need to give total activities completed by each unique goal.

From activities table:

```
    Schema::create('activities', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->string('activity');
            $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');});
```

From goals table:

```
    Schema::create('goals', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('target_number_of_activities');
                    $table->string('activity');
        $table->date('goal_start');
        $table->date('goal_end');
                    $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade'); });
```

From controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $query = DB::table('activities')
        ->join('goals', 'activities.user_id', 'goals.user_id')
        ->select('activities.*', 'goals.*')
        ->where('goals.user_id', auth()->id())
        ->whereRaw('activities.date >= goals.goal_start')
        ->whereRaw('activities.date <= goals.goal_end')
        ->whereRaw('activities.activity = goals.activity')
        ->get(); 

    $progress_against_goal = $query->count();   

    $goals = Goal::where('user_id', auth()->id())->get();
}
```

From Blade view:

```
@foreach ($goals as $goal)
    <tr><td>{{$goal->target_number_of_activities}}</td>
    <td>{{$goal->activity}}</td>
    <td>{{$goal->goal_start)</td>
    <td>{{$goal->goal_end)</td>
    <td>{{ $progress_against_goal }}</td></tr>
@endforeach
```

I only manage to get a total amount of completed activities ($progress_against_goal) for ALL goals. I need to give total activities completed by each unique goal.

Comment: does the activities belong to any goal as long as they are between `goal_start` and `goal_end` ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, as long as it obviously also matches the type of activity too.

Comment: since an activity is in the Database, it's counted as completed right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the relation between `Goal` model and `Activities` Model.

```
class Goal extends Model
{
    public function activities()
    {
        $query = Activities::where('date', '>=', $this->goal_start)->where('date', '<', $this->goal_end)->where('activity', '=', $this->activity);
        return $this->newHasMany($query, $this, 'user_id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function getProgressAttribute()
    {
        return $this->activities()->count();
    }
}
```

**controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $goals = Goal::where('user_id', auth()->id())->get();
}
```

**blade**

```
@foreach ($goals as $goal)
    <tr><td>{{$goal->target_number_of_activities}}</td>
    <td>{{$goal->activity}}</td>
    <td>{{$goal->goal_start)</td>
    <td>{{$goal->goal_end)</td>
    <td>{{$goal->progress}}</td></tr>
@endforeach
```

***Disclamer:*** this relation works only with an instance of the model `Goal`, it wont work in a query builder like

```
Goal::with('activities')->get();
//or
Goal::withCount('activities')->get();
```